# Error executing query, using ajax?

Tags: coldfusion

I'm updating a query using a form and ajax.
I added a new column (select option) to the form, it work before adding the select option.
I'm trying to get the value of the #dept_id# but i keep getting error 
'NetworkError: 500 Error Executing Database Query'.

This has to do with the update query I have in delete_record.cfc.
when adding dept=#selectDept# to the query is when i get the error.
Taking this part off the query works and it updates.
Below its the form and after that its the delete_record.cfc file.

I also made a http://jsfiddle.net/6focvy54/4/ 
where I poster the ajax call and have the delete_record.cfc file code.

```
<form method="post" action="" id="confrm_key">   
  <table >
    <tr>              
        <th >Add?</th>
        <th >Delete?</th> 
    </tr>                                                                                         
    <cfoutput query="total">          
        <tr id="hd#emp_id#">                                 

        <td>          
         <select name="selectDept" >
            <option selected="selected"  >Select Department</option>
            <cfloop query="department">
                <option value="#dept_id#">#dept_name#</option>
            </cfloop>
        </select>
          </td>
        <td> <input type="checkbox" name="check_delete"  value="#emp_id#" >Yes</td>  
        </tr>       
    </cfoutput> 

    </table>
         <p><input type="button"  name="Submit" value="Remove" onclick="sub_keys();"></p> 
 </form>
```

Comment: The error message says NetworkError.  That means it might not be your code.

Comment: The form argument you have for your delete method can be removed. The form scope will always exists and it will be a struct, definitely not a string.

Comment: You'll need to figure out exactly what's being passed to your CFC. For example, your "selected" option has no value so (if I understand this) the value of form.selectDept is going to be the string "Select Department" - that's not what you want. you are probably looking for a number - so your query bombs.

Comment: BTW, it is much harder to debug cfc's once you plug them into ajax. Always test cfc's manually *before* plugging them into ajax. Be sure to test with a) valid b) invalid *and* c) missing parameters. Nine times out of ten, that will catch any problems. In this case, I suspect Mark is correct. The function is being passed an invalid value, or it is missing altogether, causing a syntax error.

Comment: when i dump the form i got SELECTDEPT - Select Department,Select Department,Select Department,CHECK_DELETE  -844

Comment: Well as Mark said, you are passing it an invalid value. "Select Department,Select Department,Select Department" does not look like a valid ID number to me. You need to test the form *without* ajax first. Debug it the usual way so you can see the actual errors on screen. Do not add ajax into the mix until the cfc actually works with your form.

Comment: Wrap the variables being used in your query with `cfqueryparam` or at the very LEAST put single quotes around the non-numeric values. I suspect a non-numeric string is being passed as your department, which is breaking the SQL syntax.

Also, you should validate the data you're looping over the FORM fields. Don't assume just because your values are set as the page renders doesn't mean they won't be changed to something unexpected.